# running a python script from web browser to control Piface relay

Tags: python, linux, apache, cgi, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi with piface digital attached.I have apache web server running on it and have saved some python scripts to turn on and off the relay.I can run the scripts from the Rpi itself but when I try to access them from a web browser connected to the same network I get an error.

here is my script to turn on the relay

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb
import pifacedigitalio

cgitb.enable()

pifacedigital = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital()
pifacedigital.relays[0].turn_on()
```

this hello world script works the way I want from the web browser

```
#!/usr/bin/env

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "Hello World"
```

when I point the browser to my relay on script I get the following error log

[click here for error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDZp9.png)

I hope someone can make sense of the error log.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What webserver are you using to execute the code? Normally the webserver executes code under the default user of the webserver

Try adding the webserver user to the spi group:

$ groupadd spi
$ gpasswd -a Webserveruser spi

Comment: If you have further questions for the OP, ask them in a comment, not as an answer.